# Observer pattern, avoid reduntant updates when an observer can observe multiple subjects?

Tags: design-patterns

Consider the following scenario, where a directed edge from A to B conveys that B observes A, or equivalently, A might notify B for its state changes:

[image]

It is pretty apparent that the classic observer scheme here has a problem with reduntant updates, for instance:

1. `Topbar` changes its state. As a result `SecondaryTopbar, Gallery, Toolbar, Captions` get notified.
2. `SecondaryTopbar` changes its state as a result of `Topbar`'s notification, and notifies `Topbar, Gallery, Toolbar, Captions`
3. `Toolbar` changes its state twice, once because `Topbar` changed, and once cause `SecondaryTopbar` did.
4. `Captions` would get notified four times for a single update in `Topbar` in the worst case scenario, because `Toolbar` and `SecondaryTopbar`notified once, and `Toolbar` did twice.

> There are two specialized ChangeManagers. SimpleChangeManager is naive
> in that it always updates all observers of each subject. In contrast,
> DAGChangeManager handles directed-acyclic graphs of dependencies
> between subjects and their observers. A DAGChangeManager is preferable
> to a SimpleChangeManager when an observer observes more than one
> subject. In that case, a change in two or more subjects might cause
> redundant updates. The DAGChangeManager ensures the observer receives
> just one update. SimpleChangeManager is fine when multiple updates
> aren't an issue.

Mine would look like a good use case for such `DAGChangeManager`, but its implementation details are kind of unclear to me and couldn't find helpful material online. So my doubts are:

1. Are you supposed to keep a single DAG containing all the observers and subjects, or there should be a different DAG for each subject/observable in `DAGChangeManager`?
2. How do you maintain the invariant when a new observer is registered?
3. Is acyclicity enough to guarantee that every single observer will be notified at least once and only once? Shouldn't it also be connected?

Comment: Only commenting on point 3: an acyclic graph could still result in an observer being notified more than once. Suppose that both B and C observe A, and D observes both B and C. Then a change to A could result in D being notified twice: once through B and once through C. Also, no updates would flow between disconnected subgraphs - you wouldn't want them to, as the disconnect reflects a lack of interest in the updates. All that said, you wouldn't rely on properties of the graph itself (such as its being acyclic) to prevent repeated updates - this is what you need the change manager for.

Comment: With the Observer pattern described in `Design Patterns` by Gamma et al if  an object is notified of a change to some other object and as a result updates its state and notifies *its* observers, then you would get into an infinite loop with TOPBAR and SECONDARY TOPBAR endlessly notifying one another of a change *unless* at some point the states of each reach some steady state and no longer change and it is somehow recognized that the "new" state an observer would otherwise be setting is not different than its current state and therefore there is no need to update its state.  (More...)

Comment: How do your managers prevent this infinite loop yet ensure that each observer is notified of that latest, steady state reached for any object it is observing? Providing some code for these managers would be useful.

Comment: @Booboo: addressing your second comment, my scenario is purely hypothetical, it just seemed to me as a good one where to apply this pattern. I suppose that relying on `ChangeManager` to carry the notification via traversing its graph, one could only have to pay attention not to call `notify()` inside its `update()`, and no redundant updates would happen. But the structure doesn't enforce this constraint of not having redundant updates, so what's the point of bothering if you're still required to pay attention?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the *Mediator* pattern. It helps you to decouple the components/modules and to lift the cyclic relationship.
This means, don't let the components/mdules notify each other directly. Instead use a mediator.

Given are three components `A`, `B`and `C`. All components/modules need to observe the state changes of each other. When either changes its state it notifies other components about the change. Each component handles the notification by changing its own state.
To break up the cyclic relationship every component/module for example `A`, uses the `ComponentMediator` component to broadcast a notification to all registered listeners after a state change. The other components for example `B` and `C` listen to the mediator and handle the notifications e.g. by transitioning into a new state.

Now, because the initial change was broadcasted by `A`, the components `B` and `C` (or the receivers in general) do not broadcast their change of state any longer.
In other words, only *active* state changes are broadcasted. Passive state changes, those that were triggered by a broadcast, are silent.

When introducing a broadcast payload, the receivers are enabled to filter the broadcasted notifications e.g. by the broadcasting source.

Because registering with the `ComponentMediator` and handling its broadcasted events is anonymous (using polymorphism), the whole pattern is highly extensible.

It's important that every broadcaster/receiver uses the same `ComponentMediator` instance in order to communicate in the same context.
Defining the `ComponentMediator` members as static or defining `ComponentMediator` using the Singleton pattern should be avoided to prevent static dependencies.
Static dependencies would significantly complicate unit testing and introduce severe class design issues.
Also for managed languages static dependencies prevent all participating instances including their internal dependencies (i.e. the complete dependency graph starting from the static root) and allocated resources from ever being garbage collected which therefore creates a memory leak.

A small Java example to highlight the pattern:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Instantiate the components using a shared mediator instance.        
        ComponentMediator sharedMediator = new ComponentMediator();

        ComponentA = new ComponentA(sharedMediator);
        ComponentB = new ComponentA(sharedMediator);
        ComponentC = new ComponentA(sharedMediator);
    }
}

public class ComponentMediator
{
    private List<Component> listeners;
    
    public ComponentMediator() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<Component>();
    }
    
    public broadcastStateChanged(Component changedComponent) {
        BroadcastArgs eventArgs = new BroadcastArgs(changedComponent);
        
        for (Component listener : listeners) {

            // Don't notify the original broadcaster
            if (listener == changedComponent) {
                continue;
            }
            
            listener.Notify(eventArgs);
        }
    }
    
    public void registerListener(Component listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
    
    public void unregisterListener(Component listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

public class BroadcastArgs
{
    private Component source;
    
    public BroadcastArgs(Component source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
    
    public Component GetSource() {
        return this.source;
    }
}

public interface StateChangedListener {
    
    void Notify(BroadcastArgs eventArgs);
}

public abstract class Component implements StateChangedListener {
    
    private ComponentMediator mediator;
    
    protected Component(ComponentMediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
        this.mediator.registerListener(this);
    }
    
    protected ComponentMediator getMediator() {
        return this.mediator;
    }
    
    // Called by the subclass to broadcast a state change
    protected void OnStateChanged() {
        ComponentMediator mediator = getMediator();
        mediator.broadcastStateChanged(this);
    }
    
    // TODO::Add other common state related attributes.
}

public class ComponentA extends Component {
    
    public ComponenA(ComponentMediator mediator) {
        super(mediator);
    }
    
    public void Notify(BroadcastArgs eventArgs) {

        // TODO::Handle state change of BroadcastArgs.GetSource().
        // For example only handle notification that are broadcasted
        // by a particular source (event filter).
        Component broadcaster = eventArgs.GetSource();
        if (broadcaster instanceof ComponentC) {
            // TODO::Do handle event

            // Because this is a passively triggered state change, 
            // we don't broadcast any changes.
        }
    }
    
    // Some operation that changes the current state
    private void ChangeComponentState() {
        // TODO::Do some state related changes
        
        // Broadcast the change using the ComponentMediator
        OnStateChanged();
    }
}

public class ComponentB extends Component {
    
    public ComponentB(ComponentMediator mediator) {
        super(mediator);
    }
    
    public void Notify(BroadcastArgs eventArgs) {
        // TODO::Handle state change of BroadcastArgs.GetSource().
        // Because this is a passively triggered state change, 
        // we don't broadcast any changes.
    }
    
    // Some operation that changes the current state
    private void ChangeComponentState() {
        // TODO::Do some state related changes
        
        // Broadcast the change using the ComponentMediator
        OnStateChanged();
    }
}

public class ComponentC extends Component {
    
    public ComponentC(ComponentMediator mediator) {
        super(mediator);
    }
    
    public void Notify(BroadcastArgs eventArgs) {
        // TODO::Handle state change of BroadcastArgs.GetSource().
        // Because this is a passively triggered state change, 
        // we don't broadcast any changes.
    }
    
    // Some operation that changes the current state
    private void ChangeComponentState() {
        // TODO::Do some state related changes
        
        // Broadcast the change using the ComponentMediator
        OnStateChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Theres other ways to do this, but this is the cleanest and best way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution was already mentioned, but an alternative I was thinking of is to send a root change ID (or a timestamp) alongside other data into every signal. This way, components could keep track of updates and ignore them if they already reacted to them. But this can lead to another problem: not having the *latest* state from the updates. You will respond to the first only (because you don't know when a new one is the last one).