DagBased ChangeManager in observer pattern
I was reading the GOF book and i found a variation of observer pattern in which it is said that if one observer is observing more than one observeable, using DagChangeManager will be helpful.

I need help, how we can implement the DagChangeManager.
and also how one observer can observe more than one oserveable, can we use the Vec(Observeable) directly because each Observeable can have different methods for accessing the data.
like one Observeable is telling about whether temprature and other is telling about let say new stock in the store.
How we will manage this also
I am newbie in this,
any help will be really appriciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76758618/4123703 seems relevant. Instead of solving DAG, try another approach.

I'm sorry, but I must say this. How did you dig yourself into a design pattern hellhole to the point where you're solving graph reachability problems just to start writing a program? How is any of this remotely helpful to solving the actual problem the program is supposed to solve?

@PasserBy actually I got confused as in the name itself it is DagChangeManager so i was thinking like graph things

My comment was saying stop whatever you're doing with design patterns and just write the program.
